# Define max relation in ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Story model has a ManyToMany relationship with Genre model. I want to be able set maximum 2 genres to one story. How to do that? P.S. using serilaizers, viewsets and I am used forwardfunc in migrations to provide default genres in  DB

```
class Story(models.Model):
    ...
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre)

class Genre(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
class Story(models.Model):
    # model code
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre)

    def clean(self, *args, **kwrgs):
         if self.genre.count() > 2:
           raise ValidationError('Error')
         super(Story, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

hope it helps.

Comment: actually here is one good thing and bad thing for this type of solution. Good thing is this will make sure whenever Story model is updated there will be no more two genre of any story but bad thing is it is not very front-end friendly.  This will raise `Assertionerror` if this is not catch properly then proper message won't be shown. 
Better for this type of case through your custom error ( or at least proper error with proper message) Or catch this type of thing through serializer.

Comment: brings error - ``` needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used``` in line ```if self.genre.count() > 2:```